# Python cv2 .mp4 codec unable to be displayed in browser

Tags: python, opencv

When I record my webcam using the below Python code, it saves it into webcam.mp4. 
On my local computer I am able to view the video, but when I display it in my browser, it doesn't work. It seems, that the codec is wrong, but I have not figured out why, nor how to get it correct.

The Python code

```
    global rec_bool
    rec_bool = False

    def timer(seconds):
        global rec_bool
        rec_bool = True
        time.sleep(seconds)
        rec_bool = False

    seconds = 3
    timer_thread = threading.Thread(target=timer, args=(seconds,)).start()
    vid_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    vid_cod = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
    output = cv2.VideoWriter("webcam.mp4", vid_cod, 20.0, (640,480))
    while(rec_bool == True):
        ret,frame = vid_capture.read()
        
        output.write(frame)

    vid_capture.release()
    output.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The HTML code

```
<iframe class="video" id="webcam_video" src="/static/videos/webcam.mp4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

It just shows a loading symbol. When I on the other hand use curl to download it, it works perfectly fine. I have tried with other mp4 files, and they work, like they should.

Comment: what does `curl` have to do with anything here?

Comment: To check if the client can receive it. It works, so I don't see a problem there, only the output file of cv2 is odd.

Comment: what client? are you keeping any important information to yourself?

Comment: With client I mean the end user using the website on their machine :)

Comment: and what website is that? what is its relation to the situation? how is it made?

Comment: browser doesn't have to display video from all codecs. You should check in internet what codecs you can use with your browser.

Comment: Yes @furas, but how do I change my current code to make it compatible with browsers?

Comment: you may need different value in `fourcc(*'mp4v')`

Comment: or you can use program [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) to convert it to other formats. You can use it directly in console or  you can use Python wrapers like [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) or [MoviePy](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy)

Comment: Thank you @furas. Using vid_cod = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'H264') instead works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not all codecs work in web browser. See in Wikipedia: [HTML5 video](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video)

For all browsers should work codec `H.264` so you can try

```
vid_cod = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'H264')
```

---

If this can't work - ie. when `cv2` was compiled without this codec - then you can convert it with external tools like [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/)

In system console/shell

```
ffmpeg -i webcam.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -f mp4 output.mp4
```

In code

```
os.system("ffmpeg -i webcam.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -f mp4 output.mp4")
```

or

```
import subproces

# with `shell=True`
subproces.run("ffmpeg -i webcam.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -f mp4 output.mp4", shell=True)

# without `shell=True`
subproces.run( ["ffmpeg", "-i", "webcam.mp4", "-vcodec", "libx264", "-f", "mp4", "output.mp4"] )
```

or using modules like [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) or [MoviePy](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy) which use [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/).

---

**BTW:** `ffmpeg` installs also program `ffprobe` which may show details about codecs used in file.

```
 ffprobe webcam.mp4
```

---

**EDIT:**

You can also use `ffmpeg` to record from [WebCam](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Webcam)

For Linux (which I use)

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -t 00:00:03 output.mp4
```

or with some settings

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 20 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video0 -t 00:00:03 output.mp4
```

`3 seconds` = `-t 00:00:03` or `-t 3`

For other systems you should find information in documentation [WebCam](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Webcam)